# Logstash Grok filter

Tags: logstash-configuration

can anybody help me with creating the grok filter for the below logs pattern 
Current grok filter works if you remove the first line from the logs line
"message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} [%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}] "%{WORD:verb} %{DATA:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response:int} (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes:int}) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}'

Combined apache pattern didn't work.

Logs example:- 
16387 172.16.8.104 10.100.6.1 [11/Mar/2016:04:10:30 +0100] "GET /test/theme/test_Test_displaytag.css;jsessionid=1fjeyhu11wnj41wkuouxhos9nr HTTP/1.0" 200 5737 0 38933 + 1754 6073 Test.com  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ 
to build it like below

```
%{NUMBER:nubber:int} %{IP:ip1} %{IP:ip2} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "%{WORD:method} %{DATA:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}"
```